# sleep() function (python)

Tags: python, sockets, function, sleep, irc

```
  if data.find('!google') != -1:
     nick = data.split('!')[ 0 ].replace(':','')
     try:
       gs = GoogleSearch(args)
       gs.results_per_page = 1
       results = gs.get_results()
       for res in results:
         sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " " + res.title.encode("utf8") + '\r\n')
         sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " " + res.url.encode("utf8") + '\r\n')
         print
     except SearchError, e:
       sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " " + "Search failed: %s" % e + " " + '\r\n')
```

Ok I'm trying to make the script wait a few seconds before another user can "!google" to prevent users from flooding the channel or the bot, not sure if I should use the sleep() function because that might stop the whole script, I just want to make it wait a few seconds before anyone can use "!google" again.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [`sleep` function](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.sleep) inside the [`time` module](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html).

However, to make your script not block, you can call the [`time` function](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.time) in the [`time` module](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) and store that. If the current time is less than that plus, say, five seconds, don't allow them to use it.

For example:

```
last_google = 0
# somewhere later in the script where last_google is still in scope...
if data.find('!google') != -1:
    if last_google + 5 < time.time():
        # throttled
        return
    last_google = time.time()
    # do something here
```

Comment: How would I go about doing that, can you show me an example please?

Comment: @SourD: I added an example a while ago; you may have refreshed before I added it.

Comment: What should I put where it says # throlled? and what should I return?

Comment: @SourD: Throttled means they did it more than once in less than 5 seconds. It depends on your application on what you want to do there. Usually you'll want to ask them to wait a few seconds or something. You don't even have to return; just use an `else:` statement if you don't want to use `return`.